# Is it possible to get class name when implementing malloc_logger function in iOS?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, malloc, objective-c-runtime

From [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/malloc.c.auto.html), we know if `malloc_logger` global function is defined, it will be called whenever there is a malloc or free operation. I want to use it to record memory allocations in my app like this:

```
typedef void(malloc_logger_t)(uint32_t type,
                uintptr_t arg1,
                uintptr_t arg2,
                uintptr_t arg3,
                uintptr_t result,
                uint32_t num_hot_frames_to_skip);
extern malloc_logger_t *malloc_logger;
void my_malloc_stack_logger(uint32_t type, uintptr_t arg1, uintptr_t arg2, uintptr_t arg3, uintptr_t result, uint32_t num_hot_frames_to_skip); 
malloc_logger = my_malloc_stack_logger; 

void my_malloc_stack_logger(uint32_t type, uintptr_t arg1, uintptr_t arg2, uintptr_t arg3, uintptr_t result, uint32_t num_hot_frames_to_skip)
{
    // do my work
}
```

In `my_malloc_stack_logger`, I can directly get the allocated size and address. But how about object types? I want to record the class name if it is an `NSObject` instance. Is it possible to get this information?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve here, specifically? When objects are allocated, `malloc` is called to create space for them in memory, but `malloc` is not told what the space will be used for; the logger won't be able to tell the difference between setting aside space for an object, or an array of integers, or a block of memory for a string, or anything else. Depending on what you want to do, there are significantly better higher-level tools to profile an app. What are you trying to do with this information?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I want to write a debug tool that helps me to detect memory leaks. Every time a new view controller is about to be pushed into navigation stack, it generates a memory snapshot. Then when this view controller is popped out, another snapshot is generated. I'll repeat this process a few times then check if memory keeps growing and if so, I want to know what objects are not released. Allocations in Instruments is too heavy and I want a more convenient tool.

Comment: @P.Tsin i'm doubtful that `malloc_logger` gets called at all. The resource you are referring to is quite outdated and the [latest version](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1439.40.11/) doesn't have such symbol declared in the whole project. Did you manage to have it called upon memory allocation with your implementation?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind The link provided is indeed decades old, and `malloc` has loooooooong since moved out of `libc` and into `libmalloc` on Darwin platforms, but `malloc_logger` is still present there: https://opensource.apple.com/source/libmalloc/libmalloc-317.40.8/src/malloc.c.auto.html

Comment: @P.Tsin When you say "Allocations in Instruments is too heavy", what do you mean? Instruments is _the_ tool to do this sort of work in, and will very likely get you the best results: the information it can give you significantly improves on what you could get from `malloc_logger`, and it's very accurate.

Comment: @ItaiFerber In my daily work, Instruments is a tool I'll use only when issues are reported, and whenever I use it I have to profile the project first, then spend some time collecting and analyzing data. If there's a tool directly integrated into the project and can show memory info whenever I use the app, it'll be quite efficient.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the hook, it looks like what you want to achieve is not quite possible.

First problem here is that if you try to read a class name from within this function (by calling any of [`object_getClassName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418547-object_getclassname?language=objc), [`class_getName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418635-class_getname?language=objc)
or [`NSStringFromClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395143-nsstringfromclass?language=objc)), this action on its own tends to trigger new allocations. That apparently happens because some Cocoa classes load lazily. I noticed however that when requesting all classes with [`objc_getClassList`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418579-objc_getclasslist?language=objc) it makes a lot of preliminary allocations that helps to avoid them later on. So my idea is to cache all class names before subscribing to the allocations hook and refer to the cached values when needed. For the storage I used Apple's [`CFMutableDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfmutabledictionary?language=objc):

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef objc_class_records;

void refresh_objc_class_list(void) {
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&objc_class_records_mutex);
    if (objc_class_records) {
        CFRelease(objc_class_records);
    }
        
    objc_class_records = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    
    // The buffer needs to accomodate at least 26665 instances
    static const unsigned buffer_length = 100000;
    Class registered_classes[buffer_length];
    objc_getClassList(registered_classes, buffer_length);
    
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < buffer_length; ++i) {
        if (!registered_classes[i]) {
            break;
        }
        const Class class = registered_classes[i];
        const CFStringRef class_name = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, class_getName(class), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        CFDictionarySetValue(objc_class_records, class, class_name);
        CFRelease(class_name);
    }
    
}
```

Be advised that you **don't** want to have it called when the malloc logger is enabled (especially from within the hook itself).

Now you need to obtain a `Class` instance from the Objective-C objects. Depending on the type of allocation, the pointer argument goes to fifth or third parameter:

```
void my_malloc_logger(uint32_t type, uintptr_t param0, uintptr_t param1, uintptr_t param2,
                      uintptr_t param3, uint32_t frames_to_skip) {
    
    void *ptr = NULL;
    unsigned size = 0;
    
    switch (type) {
        case MALLOC_OP_MALLOC:
        case MALLOC_OP_CALLOC:
            ptr = (void *)param3;
            size = (unsigned)param1;
            break;
        case MALLOC_OP_REALLOC:
            ptr = (void *)param3;
            size = (unsigned)param2;
            break;
        case MALLOC_OP_FREE:
            ptr = (void *)param1;
            break;
    }
    
    id objc_ptr = (id)ptr;
    Class objc_class = object_getClass(objc_ptr);
    if (!objc_class) {
        return;
    }

    const CFStringRef class_name;
    const bool found = CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(objc_class_records, objc_class, (const void **)&class_name);

    if (found) {
        const static unsigned name_max_length = 256;
        char c_class_name[name_max_length];
        if (CFStringGetCString(class_name, c_class_name, name_max_length, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) {
            const char *alloc_name = alloc_type_name(type);
            nomalloc_printf_sync("%7s: Pointer: %p; Size: %u; Obj-C class: \"%s\"\n", alloc_name, objc_ptr, size, c_class_name);
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

And now why it won't work as expected:

1. [`object_getClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418629-object_getclass?language=objc) is not able to tell whether a pointer is an object of Cococa classes at the time of allocation (it will find the class, however, when the object is already allocated, e.g. before deallocation). Thus, the following code:

```
[NSObject new];
```

Will produce output similar to this:

```bash
 CALLOC: Pointer: 0x600000600080; Size: 16
   FREE: Pointer: 0x600000600080; Size: 0; Obj-C class: "NSObject"
```

2. Most of the standard Cocoa classes are in fact so-called [Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) and under the hood the actual allocation happens for an instance of a private class (which is not always recognisable by its public interface), thus this information is incomplete and sometimes misleading.

There are also many other factors which need to be taken into account (which i didn't cover here because it's beyond the question asked): the way you output data to standard output should not cause allocation by itself; the logging needs synchronisation since allocation happens a lot from any number of threads; if you want to enable/disable recording the Objective-C classes (or update the cache occasionally) access to the storage also needs to be synchronised.

Having that said if you are satisfied with what can be done with it, feel free to refer to [the repository I made](https://github.com/TheDreamsWind/SO-a-73323812-5690248-TDWMallocLogger) where this approach is already implemented in a form of a static library.

Comment: Thanks. I've learnt a lot from your answer. BTW, if I only need to record allocations & deallocations of Cocoa objects so that I'm able to browse all living objects at any time when app is running, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @P.Tsin As far as i can see it's impossible to make this function work like this. First, because the library is Objective-C-agnostic (it was built for C in the first place and doesn't provide any facilities over which type of instances to track); And second because of the reasons mentioned in the answer - even Objective-C runtime doesn't recognise Objective-C classes upon allocation, this information exist only when class instantiation is completed. You can, however, swizzle `alloc` method of `NSObject` instead and just use it instead of the allocation hook.